# ComboBox issue on Mac applet UI

Tags: java, macos, swing, nullpointerexception, applet

I am new to java swing and applet UI, i have developed a applet to run on mac and windows, The functionality works fine , But the UI in Mac specially when i try to select the items in combo box disfigures the shape (Scrambles) and doesn't show values as in image below. But the same UI works fine in Windows. 
i Have tried to add these lines in my code at start of applet still it does not work.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

and also set the combo boxes opaque using

```
group.setOpaque(true);

exception occurred is
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter.paintSelectedMenuItemBackground(AquaMenuPainter.java:153)
at com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.paintComponent(AquaComboBoxRenderer.java:151)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:227)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:317)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
```

Below i have attached the images

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you the same issue in another browser in Mac? Probably you need to refresh your Java Browser plugin.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy  i have tried it with other browsers same issue, and in eclipse(mac) when it is run as applet same issue

Comment: Does setting the look and feel to `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` help?

Comment: @dARKpRINCE not working

Comment: Try debugging the application and see if the content of the combo box is filled properly. Looks like the popup menu of the combo box does appear.

Comment: @dARKpRINCE the contents are filling in windows machine,Only in Mac it is giving problem

Comment: Exceptions when i debugged in java console:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter.paintSelectedMenuItemBackground(AquaMenuPainter.java:153)
 at com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.paintComponent(AquaComboBoxRenderer.java:151)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
 at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:227)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:317)

Comment: at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
 at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
 at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)t javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)

Comment: This is clearly some kind of issue in combobox renderer painting method, probably due to missing selected element in the list - this is as much as i can say by looking @ `AquaMenuPainter.paintSelectedMenuItemBackground()` method code. If you provide the code of your combobox I might be able to say more

Comment: Don't put a stack trace in comments.  It should be [part of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24554489/edit)!  Also use code formatting for code, input/output (like stack traces) & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code at start of your design it will work fine , I was facing the same issue too.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

and

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal");
```

Here is the link for java doc for the issue faced in UI

[Java Doc for UI look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Comment: Thanks its working.now values are displaying in dropdown on mac.

Comment: @pravi you are welcome, here is another solution which may work for you UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

Comment: Just out of curiosity: That's exactly what I suggested in comments... How come its working now?

Comment: @dARKpRINCE UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal"); worked for him i guess.