# Why is my Java program using elements of aqua LAF and the System LAF at the same time?

Tags: java, macos, look-and-feel

I have an application made in Java. When I run it from eclipse with the cross platform LAF (Metal)
`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());`

it shows JButtons and some other components in metal, JSpinners using Aqua, and JComboBoxes use aqua and don't work properly. They actually throw:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter.paintSelectedMenuItemBackground(AquaMenuPainter.java:153)
at com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxRendererInternal.paintComponent(AquaComboBoxRenderer.java:151)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:227)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:317)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
```

The app works great with Aqua. The problem persisted when I exported it as a native .app using JWrapper and ran it on another mac with Mavericks instead of Yosemite.

I am trying to make my program work with whatever LAF its forced to use (Aqua, metal, or any other), so this is a bit of a problem.

Also, it seems to be the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554489/combobox-issue-on-mac-applet-ui) but the solutions suggested are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have been wrestling with this question for over an hour before I decided to post the question. I figured out the answer seconds later.

```
private static JLabel... = new JLabel("example");
private static JButton...= new JButton("example");
//Things up here will display as aqua


public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        JLabel... =new JLabel("example");
        //things down here will display as metal
```

It was a stupid mistake.